# multiple options for a community connector configuration in Google Data Studio

Tags: looker-studio

Is there anyway to generate a list during the configuration based on what is put in the first grouping? I know for example the Google Analytics connector has Account-> Property -> View which you have to select before you are setup.

I'd like to create a connector where if you put in a web address it pulls in a list of the end points for that specific site which are listed in a json file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update (2020/05/05): This can now be achieved through [Stepped configuration](https://developers.google.com/datastudio/connector/stepped-configuration) in Community Connectors.

Original: Right now, the configuration is not dynamic.

That means you cannot pull in data from external sources during the configuration or update configuration values based on something already selected in the configuration.

The alternative now is to have flat lists of selections.

This might get updated in future.

Comment: I suppose we still cannot do async fetches for config options?

Comment: Apps Script does not support async. So, no. No async fetches for config options. You can get around it by creating your connector is Cloud Functions (or somewhere else) and using Apps Script as a wrapper.

Comment: I meant simply fetching the config options from the underlying data source... is it possible?

Comment: I'm not sure what exactly you mean by that. Could you please explain a bit more? Are you referring to `configparams` in `request` object for both `getData` and `getSchema`?