# Multiple options in custom connector configuration

Tags: connector, looker-studio

As answered in [multiple options for a community connector configuration in Google Data Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46202874/multiple-options-for-a-community-connector-configuration-in-google-data-studio), it seem no possible this.

As far as we can see now, for connectors like Adwords, DCM and Google Sheets the configuration is dynamic (updating configuration values based on something already selected in the configuration).

Anybody have any clue on how this is being done?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update (2020/05/05): This can now be achieved through [Stepped configuration](https://developers.google.com/datastudio/connector/stepped-configuration) in Community Connectors.

Original: Adwords, DCM, and Google Sheets are native connectors in Data Studio. Community Connectors are implemented differently using Apps Scripts and thus have limited functionality compared to some native connectors.

That said, if you would benefit from this feature, please [submit a feature request / vote for it](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=321382&template=0).